# Continuous dependence of the constant of the mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and $x,y:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ two other functions.

For each $t\in \mathbb{R}$, using the mean value theorem, there exists a function $C:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x(t))-f(y(t))=C(t)(x(t)-y(t)).$$
To be specific, $C(t)=f'(c(t))$ where $c$ is a function such that
$x(t)\leq c(t)\leq y(t)$ or $y(t)\leq c(t)\leq x(t)$.

I want to see when $C(t)$ is continuous. I guess if we assume that the functions $x(t),y(t)$ are continuous, then $C(t)$ can be chosen to be continuous.

Here's my attempt:
Consider $U=\{t \in \mathbb{R}:x(t)\neq y(t)\}$, then $U$ is an open subset and
$$C(t)=\frac{f(x(t))-f(y(t))}{x(t)-y(t)} $$ is defined and continous on $U$. I still have to find a continuous extension of $C$ on the whole real line.

Comment: It is only continuous on $U$. On $\mathbb R$ it isn't even a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ is clearly a differentiable function. Let $x(t) = \frac{t}{1+\frac{\pi}{2}t}$ and $y(t) = t$ in a small neighborhood of $0$ and extend them however you want outside. Then a simple computation yields that around $0$ we have

$$
C(t) = -\left(\frac{2}{\pi}+t\right)\left[\frac{1}{\left( 1+\frac{\pi}{2}t \right)^2}sin\left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{\pi}{2}  \right)  - sin\left(\frac{1}{t}  \right) \right]
$$

This function is not continuous at $0$ as if you take the sequence $t_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi}$ then $C(t_n) \to -\frac{2}{\pi}$ and if you take  $t_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}}$ then $C(t_n) \to \frac{2}{\pi}$